# “with” vs “to have”

Tags: grammaticality, synonyms, ellipses, register, is-it-a-rule

I have a tendency to say things like:

> It was nice **with** cake.

Usually it's in the form of:

> It was *adjective* **with** *noun*.

whereas my wife is always correcting me to:

> It was nice **to have** cake.

I agree that the latter is correct, but I was wondering whether the use of “with” is horrible grammar.

Comment: You've probably taken the use of *with* meaning *having, in possession of* and extended it.  Modern English speakers tend to say *there was a man with a shovel* instead of *there was a man having a shovel*; my guess is that you are unwittingly extending this usage.

Comment: I don't understand your wife's correction.  Maybe she means you should say "It was nice to have it with cake".  That would mean the same as "It was nice with cake", but it's slightly more explicit.  I'm assuming that "it" refers to some other food or to a meal.  I'm not sure that's right.

Comment: "It was nice with cake" is a very unclear formulation.

Comment: A claimed 700 000+ Google hits for "is nice with cheese". Extremely commonly heard in conversation here in the NW of England (in the days when conversation was common).

Answer (score 1):

> 1. **It** was nice with cake.
> 2. **It** was nice to have cake.

In the first sentence, the *it* is referring to something, probably food, like icecream or some strawberries. You are saying that one food tastes good when eaten with another.

In the second sentence, the *it* doesn't refer to anything. It's like the *it* in "it's raining". It means that you enjoyed eating cake not long before.

You can't swap around those meanings. So if you say the first but mean the second then that is nonstandard English.

Comment: For example, this morning I said: "It was nice with a cuddle." It should have been: "It was nice to have a cuddle."?

Comment: @Invoke I've never heard the former used before, and I don't think it's correct. The only way it works with cake is if you're referring to some other dish you literally had "with cake."